# Regex: match and exclude in Java; php flavor;

Tags: java, php, regex

I need some aid with this regex:

```
(?<=.)(\^FD).*(\^FS)
```

I'm trying to match the **^FD** and **^FS** but only when they are both available on the line; and therefore exclude everything in between

```
^FO638,340^FDPermit^FS
          ^^^      ^^^

^FO638,390^FD123456^FS
          ^^^      ^^^

^FO050,500^GB700,1,3^FS
                    xxx

^FD^FS
^^^^^^
```

I've been using https://regex101.com/ to build the expression, it seems to match correctly on the web, but not in my program -> it matches everything in between **^FD** and **^FS**

Comment: Could you elaborate on "it seems to match correctly on the web, but not in my program"

Comment: It matches everything in between on regex101 too. Regex matches are always substrings of the matched string. You can't take some of with with holes in between. You can use the first group (^FD) and second group (^FS) to extract only them though. But I don't see the point as they are constant.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by **exclude**?
And, are regular expressions really necessary?

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(final String... args) {
      final String line = "^FO638,340^FDPermit^FS";
      final int fdIndex = line.indexOf("^FD") + 3;
      final int fsIndex = line.indexOf("^FS");

      if (fdIndex > -1 && fsIndex > -1) {
         line.substring(fdIndex, fsIndex);
      }
   }
}
```

If you want to exclude what's inside:

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(final String args[]) {
      final String line = "^FO638,340^FDPermit^FSdddd";
      final int fdIndex = line.indexOf("^FD");
      final int fsIndex = line.indexOf("^FS");

      if (fdIndex > -1 && fsIndex > -1) {
         System.out.println(line.substring(0, fdIndex) + line.substring(fsIndex + 3));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes they are, as afterwards I need to apply another regex to match particular bits in between the mentioned tags. Exclude means everything on the line which is not ^FD or ^FS and they both have to be present

Comment: If you tell what you need to match afterwards, I can tell you if it's possible without regex. Code is always cleaner without them, and usually faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem. This is how you use it in java and it returns the same as the regex101.com

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "^FO638,340^FDPermit^FS\n          ^^^      ^^^\n\n^FO638,390^FD123456^FS\n          ^^^      ^^^\n\n^FO050,500^GB700,1,3^FS\n                    xxx\n\n^FD^FS\n^^^^^^";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=.)(\\^FD).*(\\^FS)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
            System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
```

The output is:

```
Start index: 10 End index: 22 ^FDPermit^FS
Start index: 57 End index: 69 ^FD123456^FS
```

This is the answer in the site

```
Match 1
Full match  10-22   `^FDPermit^FS`
Group 1.    10-13   `^FD`
Group 2.    19-22   `^FS`
Match 2
Full match  57-69   `^FD123456^FS`
Group 1.    57-60   `^FD`
Group 2.    66-69   `^FS`
```

You can use the next code to print the groups

```
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
```

Comment: It does not have to match the string between ^FD and ^FS

Comment: you can use matcher.group(1) and matcher.group(2) it shows the groups

Comment: matcher.group - I'm using it to match as a particular string later on which later matches a keyword in CSS, I cannot use matcher.group here `matcher.group("FI") != null ? "keyword_field" :`

Comment: appreciate your effort, yet I cannot use matcher.group in this case

Comment: Edit your question and show what you want. A real example, so we can help you.